# What is a good compilation of songs in english for children that includes the "classic" ones?

Tags: music

I'm looking for a decent collection of classic children/nursery songs to play for my 3-year boy. The collections that I've found on Amazon are either poorly rated or, according to some reviewers, have issues with the performers.

I'm specifically looking for the "classic" songs, e.g. Twinkle Twinkle, Old MacDonald Had a Farm, the alphabet song, etc. Preferably sung in English by performers with a neutral accent.

Comment: Fred Penner, Ella Jenkins, Raffi all have some of these mixed in with other things... I miss Ella and Raffi!

Comment: I'd highly recommend recording your own voice singing those songs. Familiar voice, familiar accent, and fairly cheap =). You can obtain the melodies for free with a simple google. Just add a voice-over :)

Comment: Until I read for a 3 year old, I was going to say Rock Band on the Xbox.  I feel I have given my kids a good "classic" (rock) song experience with this game.

Comment: Also, try to find Pete Seeger's "American Favorite Ballads", a set of records containing all the folk classics like "Big Rock Candy Mountain", "Old Dan Tucker", "You are my sunshine" etc.  http://www.amazon.com/American-Favorite-Ballads-Pete-Seeger/dp/B001SGKQI6   Amazing music even if you don't have kids!

Comment: I believe this type of question is considered off topic [along the lines of which product should I buy], but I have an answer so I've answered below. Could we make this a Wiki to avoid banning the question?

Comment: Paul Cline is correct; this is a shopping request, and off topic. Community Wiki is not intended as a way to bypass the established boundaries of the site, so would not be appropriate for this (CW is for questions that are considered fairly central to the site premise, that would benefit from a single, comprehensive "canonical" answer). I'm going to have to close this.

Comment: We're currently evaluating our site, and this question is one we are seeking feedback on. Everyone, please visit [this meta question](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/343/parenting-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical) and chime in with your thoughts and votes!

Answer (score 0):

I checked out some Raffi CDs from the library and found a lot of the older songs (as well as the FANTASTIC song "Banana Phone" which I sing to this day). I think there was another CD called "Toddler's Favorites" but it also had one or two that set my teeth on edge.

If your kids like the album they will play it incessantly, so consider ripping the songs, deleting the ones that annoy you, and then burning a new CD with only the good ones.

Comment: Oh Banana Phone... I miss you.

Answer (score 0):

[Disney's Children's Favorites Vol. 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DAJA7U)
1. If you're happy and you know it
2. Shoo, Fly, Don't Bother Me
3. This Old Man (Knick-Knack Patty-Whack)
4. I've Been Working On The Railroad
5. Three Blind Mice
6. Oh, Susanna!
7. The Man On The Flying Trapeze
8. The Blue-Tail Fly (Jimmy Crack Corn)
9. The Mail Must Go Through
10. Home On The Range
11. It Ain't Gonna Rain No More
12. A Bicycle Built For Two
13. Mary Had A Little Lamb
14. Take Me Out to the Ball Game
15. Friends Lullaby
16. Old MacDonald
17. The Hokey Pokey
18. She'll Be Comin' Round The Mountain
19. Ten Little Indians
20. The Green Grass Grew All Around
21. In The Good, Old Summertime
22. Animal Fair
23. Row, Row, Row Your Boat
24. I'm A Policeman
25. Pop! Goes The Weasel
26. Dixie
27. Twinkle, Twinkle, Little Star
28. A Hunting We Will Go
29. Down In The Valley
30. Good Night, Ladies

[Disney's Children's Favorites Vol. 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DAL4U6)
1. The Wheels on the Bus
2. Froggie Went A-Courtin'
3. The Farmer In The Dell
4. Yankee Doodle
5. On Top Of Old Smoky
6. Sailing Medley
7. Camptown Races
8. Old Blue
9. Here We Go Loopty-Loo
10. The Sidewalks Of New York
11. Short'nin' Bread
12. John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmid
13. Thumbelina
14. The Bear Went Over The Mountain
15. Red River Valley
16. Skip To My Lou
17. Swanee River
18. Western Medley
19. London Bridge
20. Here We Go Round The Mulberry Bush
21. Frere Jacques
22. The Dump Truck Song
23. Bingo
24. Polly Wolly Doodle
25. There Was An Old Lady
26. Carrot Stew
27. When The Saints Go Marching In
28. There's A Hole In My Bucket
29. Meet Me In St. Louis
30. Mickey Mouse March